# In IDLE 3 python shell, how to use 'ls' command properly to get proper result

Tags: python-idle, python

I am using the following command

```
print Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

which outputs

```
b'pi\ntem\ntemp\n'
```

P.S. I am using raspberry pi which has Raspbian Linux

Comment: We don't know what your directory listing should be. So how can we say if thats wrong? But it looks like its outputting three names for directories - `pi, tem, temp` - are you sure those directories aren't there?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `ls` and not something closer to `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr i am in /home/pi/temp directory.

Comment: @mhlester well i am trying to use 'tree' command, i know getcwd() works but there's nothing for 'tree' in os library

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing the newlines `\n` and string quotes `b''` when printing the return value of Popen?

Comment: @PeterGibson yes that what i get as output in python shell

Comment: But not when *printing* the result right? Just when evaluating Popen?

Comment: no that's the output i get when printing Popen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Python 3, which differentiates between strings and byte arrays.  You need to `decode` the byte array returned by the `communicate()` method:

```
print(Popen(['ls'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

Some useful information can be found [here](http://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/).